# How can I get a conditional statement to select the most recent timestamp?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a data frame consisting of ~1,000,000 rows and am classifying some data.

Where there are two or more dates present against a record, I want to use the first date in a new field called `Day1` and the second date in a field called `Day2`.

I achieve this thus:

```
df %>%
   group_by(pii, cn) %>%
   summarise(Day1 = min(TestDate, na.rm = TRUE), # Selects the first available date
             Day2 = sort(TestDate, na.last = TRUE)[2]) # Selects the second available date
```

However, I have come across a problem affecting around 1.6% of the records (~14,000) where there are only two dates listed, which are identical.

In this case, I want to be able to look at the time listed against each date (recorded in `df$time`) to determine which came first, still with the intention of taking the first (earlier) date as `Day1` and the second as `Day2`.

How can I incorporate this into my current structure?

For the sake of an illustrative example (albeit non-functioning), I am thinking that it could be something like this:

```
if_else(sort(TestDate,na.last = TRUE)[2] == Day1, [CHECK TIMES HERE], sort(TestDate, na.last = TRUE)[2])
```

As such, I would hope for something like this as an output:

```
id   Day1        D1_Time  Day2        D2_Time
1    2021-01-02  NA       2021-01-04  NA
2    2021-01-01  04.45    2021-01-01  04.48
3    2021-01-03  NA       2021-01-08  NA
```

In this output example, the record with `id` value `2` has two identical dates listed, so the `df$time` field was consulted to determine which came first.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve your problem (though it might not answer your specific question).  I'd do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(pii, cn) %>%
  arrange(TestDate, time) %>% # order within the groups by date and time
  mutate(rownum = 1:n()) %>% # number the rows in order
  filter(rownum <= 2) %>% # only keep the top 2 in each group.  slice_head(n=2) would be an alternative to the last 2 steps, but I want the row number below
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rownum,  # spread to match your desired 
              values_from = c(TestDate, time)) %>% 
  select(pii, cn, TestDate_1, time_1, TestDate_2, time_2) #reorder the columns to match your sample
```

Or, if you don't like that approach, could you combine each date/time pair into a single datetime field, and use your original logic?